# create sequence of numbers on grouped column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

Consider below table with column a,b,c.

```
a   b   c
3   4   5
3   4   5
6   4   1
1   1   8
1   1   8
1   1   0
1   1   0
```

I need a select statement to get below output. i.e. increment column 'rn' based on group of column a,b,c.

```
a   b   c   rn
3   4   5   1
3   4   5   1
6   4   1   2
1   1   8   3
1   1   8   3
1   1   0   4
1   1   0   4
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK` analytic function to get a unique ID for each combination of A, B, and C.  Just note that if a new value is inserted into the table, the IDs of each combination of A, B, and C will shift and may not be the same.

#### Query

```sql
WITH
    my_table (a, b, c)
    AS
        (SELECT 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6, 4, 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 1, 8 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 1, 8 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 1, 0 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 1, 0 FROM DUAL)
SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY b desc, c desc, a) as rn
  FROM my_table t;
```

#### Result

```
   A    B    C    RN
____ ____ ____ _____
   3    4    5     1
   3    4    5     1
   6    4    1     2
   1    1    8     3
   1    1    8     3
   1    1    0     4
   1    1    0     4
```

Comment: Did you validate your output with OP's expected output ?

Comment: There is no logical order to the example output OP provided so unless OP says otherwise, the `RN` assigned to each combination of A, B, and C does not matter as long as it is unique for each combination.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, I updated the ordering of the analytic function to match OPs output. It doesn't make much sense to sort that way, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

As a starter: for your answer to make sense at all, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows. Let me assume that you have such column, called `id`.

Then, you can use window functions:

```
select a, b, c, 
    sum(case when a = lag_a and b = lag_b and c = lag_c then 0 else 1 end) over(order by id) rn
from (
    select t.*,
        lag(a) over(order by id) lag_a,
        lag(b) over(order by id) lag_b,
        lag(c) over(order by id) lag_c
    from mytable t
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some way of ordering your rows, then you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c, rn
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY id
  MEASURES MATCH_NUMBER() AS rn
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( FIRST_ROW EQUAL_ROWS* )
  DEFINE EQUAL_ROWS AS (
      EQUAL_ROWS.a = PREV( EQUAL_ROWS.a )
  AND EQUAL_ROWS.b = PREV( EQUAL_ROWS.b )
  AND EQUAL_ROWS.c = PREV( EQUAL_ROWS.c )
  )
)
```

So, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, a, b, c ) AS
SELECT 1, 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 6, 4, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, 1, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1, 1, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 1, 1, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 1, 1, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
>  A |  B |  C | RN
> -: | -: | -: | -:
>  3 |  4 |  5 |  1
>  3 |  4 |  5 |  1
>  6 |  4 |  1 |  2
>  1 |  1 |  8 |  3
>  1 |  1 |  8 |  3
>  1 |  1 |  0 |  4
>  1 |  1 |  0 |  4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f86de8d28f00c1ddffc2c6a373561de5)*

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done without any ordering, by getting the distinct groups and numbering each group. Borrowing the first part from EJ Egjed:

```
WITH  my_table (a, b, c)  AS
        (SELECT 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 4, 5 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6, 4, 1 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 1, 8 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 1, 8 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 1, 0 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1, 1, 0 FROM DUAL)
, groups as (select distinct a, b, c
            from my_table)
, groupnums as (select rownum as num, a, b, c 
           from groups)
select a, b, c, num
from   my_table join groupnums using(a,b,c);
```